# How to Get the Particular Fields From the response which is in json format

Tags: node.js

I wanted to extract the repoNames and their Topics from the response body
and the body contains reponames, ids, topics... 
which is the github api output
and wanted to extract the fields that are only required from the output body of the api

{

```
const request = require('request');

// configuration for the url generation
const perPages = 100;
const startPage = 1;
const endPage = 17;
const url = 'https://api.github.com/orgs/organasationName/repos?per_page=%perPages%&page=%page%';

// define a asyncronous call for one url
async function callOneUrl(url) {
    // local options for each url
    const options = {
        'method': 'GET',
        'url': url, //To get all the users data from the repos
        'headers': {
            'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json',
            'Authorization': 'Bxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'User-Agent': 'nxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        }
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(options, function (error, response) {
            if (error) return reject(error);
            resolve(response);
        });
    });
}
// call each url with a for loop
(async () => {
    for (let i = startPage; i <= endPage; i++) {
        // using the await statement to get the resolved value of the Promise instance or catch the error
        try {
            var response = await callOneUrl(url.replace('%perPages%', perPages).replace('%page%', i));
            // handle response here
            console.log(response.body);
        } catch (error) {
            // handle errors here
            throw new Error(error);
        }
    }
})()
```

the response body of the api is in json format
the response of the above code is like

```html
{
{ /////output of the above code////
 "id": 1 xxxxx '
 "name": hvvXxxxx,
 "org_id": 1 xxx,
 .
 .
 .
 "topics": ["hue", "right", "left"]
}, {
 "id": 2 xxxxx '
 "name": hvvXxxxxwww,
 "org_id": 1 xxx,
 .
 .
 .
 "topics": ["hue", "right", "go"]
}, {
 "id": 3 xxxxx '
 "name": hvvXxxxxttt,
 "org_id": 1 xxx,
 .
 .
 .
 "topics": ["hue", "right", "left", "good"]
}
}
```

Comment: can you format your code properly as it is hard to see what is your input and what you need?

Comment: @AshishModi modified the changes and i need the specific fields from the response body data of the api's output

Comment: can you also post what is the response you are getting and what is the expected response?

Comment: @AshishModi i have updated the code with the json response and i have only given the example of the code due to privacy so its the output of the github api which contains all the details of the repos and "i wanted to extract only the repo names and their topics"

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `.map` to get the required properties like this

```js
const response = [{
    "id": "1xxxxx",
    "name": "hvvXxxxx",
    "org_id": "1xxx",
    "topics": ["hue", "right", "left"]
  },
  {
    "id": "2xxxxx",
    "name": "hvvXxxxxwww",
    "org_id": "1xxx",
    "topics": ["sss", "sds"]
  }
];

console.log(response.map(i => ({
  "org_id": i.org_id,
  "topics": i.topics
})));
```

Comment: its showning an error                                                                (node:35112) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: TypeError: response.map is not a function at C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxx\Desktop\GitHUbAndFlow\GithubDataWithPaginationAuto.js:41:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
(node:35112) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try lodash lib for that.

[Pick loadash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pick)

e.g

```
const response = [{
    "id": "1xxxxx",
    "name": "hvvXxxxx",
    "org_id": "1xxx",
    "topics": ["hue", "right", "left"]
  },
  {
    "id": "2xxxxx",
    "name": "hvvXxxxxwww",
    "org_id": "1xxx",
    "topics": ["sss", "sds"]
  }
];

const expectedArr = response.map(i => _pick(i, ['name', 'topics', 'etc...']))
```

Thanks

Comment: (node:27012) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: TypeError: response.map is not a function at C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Desktop\GitHUbAndFlow\GithubDataWithPaginationAuto.js:42:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
(node:27012) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

Comment: Map always works on array. Just make sure your response is in array.

Comment: my response is in the json format could you suggest how to put it into an array because my output contains details of thousands of repo data